# jquery change html attribute isn't working

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var lines = 2;
    var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');

    $('#input').keydown(function(e) {

        newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
        linesUsed.text(newLines);

        if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
            return false;
            $("#input").attr("wrap", "off");
        }

    });
});
```

The #input applies to textarea. I want when two lines have been typed the textarea to stop wrapping. But the new attribute doesn't seem to be added. Check it out [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2).

Comment: you're returning before setting the attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use return false later:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
     $("#input").attr("wrap", "off");
     return false;//after setting attribute.
 }
```

Comment: oh wow that's it thanks. So return false ends a line of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
        return false;
        $("#input").attr("wrap", "off");
    }
```

This is returning before you set the attr.

To fix it:

```
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
       $("#input").attr("wrap", "off");
        return false;
    }
```